# Changing label text when button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, actionevent

I am trying to create a swing app that is a quiz.  I need the jLabel to change on a button click but when I click the button, the app locks up.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

My button click code is below:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String[] questions = {"test0","test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6"};
    String[] answers = {"","","","","","",""};
    int i = 0;

    do {
        jLabel2.setText(questions[i]);
        index.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        if (txtAnswer.getText().toLowerCase().equals(answers[i].toLowerCase())) {
            i++;
            jLabel2.setText(questions[i]);
        }
        else {
            add(lblWrong);
        }
    }
    while(i < 7);
}
```

I am getting a warning that the evt parameter has not been used, could this be a problem?

Thank you

Comment: shouldn't you have your labels in an array?

Comment: My labels are declared outside the actionevent method

Comment: I don't understand. You are just iterating 7 times and updating the same JLabel? What is the point of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the do while loop. It's trapping you in the button press method as if you get an answer wrong you keep entering the else and can't leave it, stopping the app from working. Replace it with an if statement checking if i < 7.

Answer (score 1):

In the `else` condition of your loop, you don't add 1 to `i` at all - therefore you can potentially end up in the situation where it's never incremented, thus it will be an infinite loop (locking your program up.)

Comment: I don't want them moving on until they get it right.  Shouldn't I only increment it in the if statement?